# Intersection Number of Stable and Unstable Manifold for Hyperbolic Fixed Point of ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Let $Q^n$ be a closed, Riemannian manifold, $TQ$ its tangent bundle with the canonical lift of the Riemannian metric (as outlined in [do Carmo](https://smile.amazon.com/Riemannian-Geometry-Manfredo-Perdigao-Carmo/dp/0817634908/)) and the resulting [compatible triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_complex_manifold#Compatible_triples), $\xi$ a complete tangent vector field on $TQ$, and $p$ [an elementary, in the notation of [Abraham-Robbin](https://smile.amazon.com/Transversal-mappings-flows-Ralph-Abraham/dp/B0006BR4GQ/)] a hyperbolic [in the rest of the universe's notation, evidently] fixed point for $\xi$. Let $W^s(p)$ and $W^u(p)$ be the stable and unstable manifolds of $p$ respectively, and suppose both are closed. If both $W^s$ and $W^u$ are orientable, orient $TQ$, $W^s$, and $W^u$ ($TQ$ is always orientable); in any case, adjust $W^s$ and $W^u$ so they are transverse to each other (although each may itself be only immersed). Let $\{q_1, q_2, \ldots, q_k\} = W^{s\prime } \cap W^{u\prime}$.

Is there any relevant information relating to $\xi$ that can be determined from the mod 2 intersection number (if either or both of $W^s$ or $W^u$ is non-orientable), integral intersection number (if both $W^s$ and $W^u$ are orientable), or integral group-ring intersection number (if $\pi_1(TQ,p)$ is known) of $W^s$ and $W^u$?

(Of course, if one only has a coordinate patch for $TQ$ with generalized (resp. symplectic) coordinates which excludes a set of measure 0 and a Lagrangian (resp. Hamiltonian) on the coordinate patch, neither the fundamental group of $TQ$ nor the fundamental group elements determined by the homoclinic loops at $p$ determined by each $q_i$ may be known, and so we may not be able to compute the $\mathbb{Z}[\pi_1(TQ,p)]$ intersection number of $W^s$ and $W^u$; the mod 2 or integral intersection number should still be computable without determining fundamental group of $TQ$, depending on whether $W^s$ and $W^u$ are both orientable.)

[Edit: According to [Abraham-Marsden](https://smile.amazon.com/Foundations-Mechanics-Ams-Chelsea-Publishing/dp/0821844385/), hyperbolic is now the standard terminology.]

Comment: Each $W^s$ and $W^u$ are always orientable because they are (globally) diffeomorphic to open disks. This follows from the Brown-Stallings lemma. If $\xi$ is a gradient vector field, intersections of stable and unstable manifolds can be used to define "Morse homology" via the Morse(-Thom-Smale-Witten) chain complex which turns out to be isomorphic to the singular homology of $Q$. This construction has also been generalized in various ways to more general $\xi$.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the application: if the intersection number is 0, the submanifolds can be made disjoint by The Whitney Trick (See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683857/intuition-regarding-the-whitney-trick)). #NoDepositNoReturn