# Perelman's theorem in dimensions other than 3 (and 4) - why is it "easy"?

Tags: differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Perelman's theorem states

> Every simply connected, closed 3-manifold is homeomorphic to the 3-sphere.

It is stated in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PwRl5W-whTs) at the 2 minute mark that proving this in dimensions other than 3 was much easier. Dimensions $1$ and $2$ are relatively easy, dimension $6$ was proven in 1962, and dimensions $5$ and $\geq7$ were proven in 1961. Michael Freedman won the Fields medal in 1982 for proving the dimension $4$ case. This left dimension $3$ which as we know was solved by Grigori Perelman in 2003. Can anyone give an explanation that I, a third year university student who has taken and understood a course in differential/Riemannian geometry and topology on manifolds, of why dimensions $3$ and $4$ were so much harder to prove than all the others?

Comment: In nutshell: Whitney trick does not work in small dimensions. Incidentally, "easy" does not mean "easily understood by an average undergraduate student who took a class in differential geometry." Incidentally, the smooth Poincare Conjecture is still open in dimension 4.

Comment: @MoisheKohan What is the "Whitney trick"?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683857/intuition-regarding-the-whitney-trick

Comment: Apologies to all about the frequent edits - I know how it messes with the site algorithm. There were a few details I had to correct.

Comment: In addition, if you wan to see a sketch of the proof of the h-cobordism theorem (which is how Poincare conjecture is proven in dimensions $\ge 5$), take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-cobordism). If you want to see more details, you can find these in Milnor's "h-cobordism theorem" book.